# Proving any polygon has equal number of in-degree and out-degree vertices

Tags: graph-theory

You are given a polygon with arrows on its sides. Prove that the number of vertices with in-degree equal to 2 is equal to the number of vertices with out-degree equal to 2.

Please, help with this one.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If there are $a$ vertices with in-degree 0, $b$ vertices with in-degree 1, $c$ degrees with in-degree 2, how many arrow-heads are there?
And how many edges are there to begin with?